# ¿Cómo puedo ocultar la flecha de un DropdownList (asp.net c#)?

Tags: html, c#, asp.net, dropdownlist

Tengo los siguientes campos de tipo DropdownList(trabajo en asp.net c#), de la siguiente manera en el HTML:

```
<asp:DropDownList ReadOnly="true" onkeyup="fncAutocompletar1200()" class="form-control" ID="ddvalor1" runat="server"Enabled="False" Font-Size="Smaller"></asp:DropDownList>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, Qué puedo hacer para ocultar la flecha de ese DropdownList?

Answer (score 0):

La flecha del SELECT no se puede ocultar con las propiedades estándar de CSS, pero los navegadores te permiten modificar su estilo con algunas propiedades propias.

Por ejemplo, el IE podés ocultar la flecha con esto:

```
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

Y en Safari, Chrome y Firefox podés ocultarlo con estas lineas:

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

Por ejemplo, podrías crear una clase de CSS para aplicarlo a los SELECTs a los que quieras eliminarle la flecha, algo así:

```
.no-arrow {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
.no-arrow::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

Y después a los DropDownList que querés que no muestren la flecha los ponés así:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="no-arrow" />
```

Espero te sirva.

¡Suerte!

Comment: en qué parte precisamente de mi código debo colocar eso?

Comment: Ahí te agregué un ejemplo, la idea sería que pongas las clases de estilo en un archivo .css, y después en el .aspx le agregues el CssClass a los DropDownList, como en el ejemplo.